# How to merge time gap in achartengine

Tags: android, merge, achartengine

I am using android achartengine library for an stock trading based application application. I am in a need that i want to merge graph of two trading sessions. I dont want to show line between market halt hours.That is 9:30AM-12:30PM and 2:30PM-5PM are two sessions. Between 12:30-2:30 is the market halt hours.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to display interrupted line in AChartEngine, you need to add null values. This means that you need to add at least one `MathHelper.NULL_VALUE` in the interval between the samples where there are no values. In your example, somewhere between 12:30 and 2:30 there needs to be a null value.

Please take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/SensorValuesChart.java) example for better understanding.

Comment: I have tried above method. It creates gap between two section of graph. I want graph to be continues. Find below the sample image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/pfcr4

Comment: Well, a gap means an empty space between 2 values. What you need is a step chart.

Comment: yes. I mean the gap between 2 values. I want x-axis value should be 2:30 after 12:30. I dont want graph is plotted for 12:30-2:30. Go through with this image for better understanding. http://www.freeimagehosting.net/pfcr4. When i using MathHelper.NULL_VALUE it creates gap between 2 parts of graph

Comment: I have no idea what you actually want.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. Follow the image link for better understanding. http://www.freeimagehosting.net/7wm1t . When i used MathHelper.NULL_VALUE the graph look like this. Its not continuous. I want graph to be continues with trimmed out the empty space.

Comment: OK. You cannot do that with ACE.